# Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение

Tags: c#

Сформировать строку типа `StringBuilder` из последних двух слов предложений исходной строки типа `String`, в которых больше трех слов и есть дата в формате `дд/мм/гггг`. Разделителями предложений считать восклицательный знак, вопросительный знак, точку и любую комбинацию этих символов. Разделителями слов считать пробел, запятую, точку с запятой, сочетание любой буквы русского алфавита с буквой ‘x’ и любую комбинацию этих разделителей. В полученной строке заключить все слова, содержащие цифры, в скобки.

Например, исходная строка:

> Мама, ax ax,, мыла   раму 25/05/2015 ух;25раз!!!  Потом  26/05/2015 смотрела, ох  долго, фх,фх Дом2!...  Без хх труда не выловишь и рыбку из пруда?!! 27/05/2015 она ых отдыхала…

Результат:

> (25/05/2015) (25раз) долго (Дом2)

```
string sensPattenr = @"[.!?]+\s*";
string wordPattern = @"[\s,;]+|\s*[а-я]х+[,\s;]";
```

Comment: Для того, чтоб вам помогли надо максимально помочь сообществу с понятием вашей задачи, а именно: 1. Входные данные. 2. То, что должно получиться. 3. Ваши попытки реализации этого всего. Помните, что учебные задания без ваших попыток на SO не любят и часто закрывают! Так что прошу вас, отредактируйте свой вопрос так, что бы у нас было как можно меньше вопросов!!

Comment: Впервые слышу о том, что в русском языке есть буквы `с буквой 'х' на конце`

Comment: EvgeniyZ я должен потом из этих предложений выбрать что подходит по условию задачи , а для этого каждое предложение на разбить на слова , но с разделителями не понятно как составить регулярку( с запятой пробелом и точкой с запятой понятно , а вот с любой буквой на конце х не понимаю)

Comment: в ответе я не уверен да это и не важно , главное сделать выражения корректно

Comment: А нужно прям ругуляркой? Или вы к этому прицепились потому, что не знаете другого способа?

Comment: нужно регуляркой

Comment: Ну, делайте `Regex.Split` по первому вашему шаблону. Потом по второму.

Answer (score 0):

Опять же попробовал чисто для себя решить эту задачу, но не через регулярные выражения (считаю их тут лишними и неправильными).

Значит имеем саму строку:

```
var data = "Мама, ax ax,, мыла раму 25/05/2015 ух;25раз!!! Потом 26/05/2015 смотрела, ох долго, фх,фх Дом2!... Без хх труда не выловишь и рыбку из пруда?!! 27/05/2015 она ых отдыхала…";
```

Теперь по порядку:

1. > Разделителями предложений считать восклицательный знак, вопросительный знак, точку и любую комбинацию этих символов.

Тут легко вроде как легко, у нас есть некий массив символов для разбития строки. Значит нам достаточно написать следующее:

```
var lines = data.Split('!', '?', '.').Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
```

`.Where` тут для того, что бы убрать `любую комбинацию этих символов`, ибо если будет скажем `!!?`, то мы получим массив с разбитым текстом и еще дополнительно пустые строки, их то мы через `Where` и убираем.

2. > Разделителями слов считать пробел, запятую, точку с запятой, сочетание любой буквы русского алфавита с буквой ‘x’ и любую комбинацию этих разделителей.

Тут тоже довольно просто, делаем все тоже самое у каждой строки. Заодно уберем пустые строки (как в первом случае) и все, что содержит злостную букву `x` (в примере часть английские и часть русские, убрал все):

```
var words = lines.Select(x => x.Split(' ', ',', ';').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && !new[] { 'x', 'х' }.Any(s.ToLower().Contains)).ToList());
```

3. > в которых больше трех слов и есть дата

Тут нам понадобиться еще они `Where()` в предыдущий запрос, но я вынесу это для наглядности отдельно. Мы попробуем каждую дату перевести в `DateTime`, ну и проверим на кол-во слов. Также мы здесь выполним следующее задание:

> В полученной строке заключить все слова, содержащие цифры, в скобки

```
var result = words.Where(x => x.Count >= 3 && x.Any(a => DateTime.TryParse(a, out _))).Select(x => x.Select(s => s.Any(char.IsDigit) ? $"({s})" : s).ToList()).ToList();
```

На этом этапе у нас будут готовые данные, которые нам остается только вывести. Я не буду делать `StringBuilder`, я просто выведу все это на консоль:

```
result.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", x.Skip(Math.Max(0, x.Count - 2)))));
```

Результат:

> (25/05/2015) (25раз)
>   долго (Дом2)

Весь код получаем примерно следующий:

```
var data = "Мама, ax ax,, мыла раму 25/05/2015 ух;25раз!!! Потом 26/05/2015 смотрела, ох долго, фх,фх Дом2!... Без хх труда не выловишь и рыбку из пруда?!! 27/05/2015 она ых отдыхала…";
var lines = data.Split('!', '?', '.').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));

var words = lines.Select(x =>
    x.Split(' ', ',', ';')
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) && !new[] {'x', 'х'}.Any(s.ToLower().Contains)).ToList());

var result = words.Where(x => x.Count >= 3 && x.Any(a => DateTime.TryParse(a, out _)))
    .Select(x => x.Select(s => s.Any(char.IsDigit) ? $"({s})" : s).ToList()).ToList();

result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", x.Skip(Math.Max(0, x.Count - 2)))));
```

Тут можно компактно все это сделать, но моя задача была более наглядно показать как можно поступить. Опять же это просто как пища для размышления и пример из которого можно немного почерпнуть знаний. Я бы на вашем месте от "регулярок" вовсе отказался бы, но дело ваше...

В общем, удачи в изучении C#!

Comment: EvgeniyZ большое спасибо за помощь , я сам пока не чувствую преимущество регулярок , но такая была задача , ещё раз огромное спасибо